# Facebook permissions dialog - why the different look?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to know why my permissions dialog looks different from the regular permissions dialog that the other apps use.

So far all apps I have tested look like this:

[image: Other apps permissions dialog]

However my app's permission dialog looks like this:
[image: My apps's permission dialog]

I guess approach 1 is preferred (because I see that everywhere).

I decorated my action with:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
```

What do I need to do to get a permissions dialog that looks like the first one shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use the [new one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/), try to change your facebook app settings.

Comment: thx! Now that I know what it is and how to control it, I think I'll stick to the new 'enhanced' dialog. I wonder why other apps have not migrated yet.
Now I have to figure out how to localize the text displayed in that dialog (title, desc, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the new auth dialog here:

`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{id}/auth`

or you can disable it here
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{id}/advanced`